# Is there a way to remove listeners created with ajaxSuccess?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

Is there a way to remove listeners created with jQuery's `ajaxSuccess`?

I would be interested in either ways to remove listeners that happen to be assigned to the variable, or ways to remove all existing `ajaxSuccess` listeners.

Another angle might be a way to trace back to what request led to the "success" in question, as well as what element-related event triggered that request; ideally analogous to the `event.target` property in "normal" event listeners.  It seems `ajaxSuccess`' `event` parameter is a different species of animal and has no `target` property and no `preventDefault` method.  Many throwers, one catcher, but no catcher identification.  Perhaps there is a tool other than `ajaxSuccess`?  Hopefully other than cooking jQuery `.ajax` from scratch...

Comment: Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? What is expected result ?

Comment: wouldn't do any good to try to prevent an element event in ajaxSuccess callback ... event will be long completed by then. What exactly are you needing to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would be interested in either ways to remove listeners that happen
>   to be assigned to the variable, or ways to remove all existing
>   ajaxSuccess listeners

Try using `.off()`

```
$(document).off("ajaxSuccess")
```

Comment: That actually worked!  I guess there's at least one thing jQuery AJAX events have in common with element events.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between element events and ajax other than what developer uses to make ajax call.

You can however modify the xhr object while setting up each request and access specific properties in the ajaxSuccess callback. These can be arbitrary properties and values that help you manage your app. For example if you wanted to pass an actual element event to the callbacks

You can also inspect the settings object which will contain the url and use that for conditional code

Simple example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'...',
    beforeSend:function(xhr){
       xhr.myData = 'some value';
    }
    ...
});

$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    console.log(xhr.myData );
})
```

Comment: If element event called `$.ajax()` could alternatively set `context` to `event.target` within `beforeSend` , which would set `this` to `event.target` : element which triggered `$.ajax()` at `.done()` , `.fail()`

Comment: So `beforeSend` can add properties to what becomes the `xhr` parameter of `.ajaxSuccess`?  Is this regarded as kludgey in the sense of using properties of `window` as a sort of global variable?  Looks as if `beforeSend` is a data transfer device by design, so probably not.  This particular trick won't help my situation (I think) because AJAX call is started by using `/something.json` (Rails route) as `source` for a jQuery API autocomplete field.

Comment: nothing global about it , that object instance is only available internally to `$.ajax`  instance. Not clear what problem you are trying to solve